# How to convert the values of a Map of List to a single List

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, data-structures, java-stream

How is the best (efficient and simple) way to convert the values of a `Map<Object1, List<Object2>>` to a `List<Object2>`. Should I simply iterate over all entries and `adAll` the items to a list?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a third way so you don't need to create an ArrayList, which is what you actually asked.  This is the proper way to use streams because you're not changing the state of any object.

```
List<Object2> values = myMap.values()
                            .stream()
                            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Java 8 required though.

Comment: This will return a List<List<String>> as myMap.values is a Collection<List<String>>

Comment: Oh right, thanks.  I didn't see that List<Object2>  I revised.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it:

```
 List<Object2> list = myMap.values()
                           .stream()
                           .flatMap(item -> item.stream())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: I misread your requirement, and deleted my answer. I thought you literally wanted a List of Lists. I think the method you gave is probably among the most efficient, barring some clever trick.

Comment: Streams shouldn't be used to change state of another object.

Comment: Just fixed the answer

Comment: Our answers are basically identical now.

Comment: And now they ARE identical.

Answer (score 0):

One option using addAll.

```
List<Object2> list = new ArrayList<>();
myMap.values().forEach(list::addAll);
```

Comment: The list doesn't change.